# React and material-ui/DatePicker: how can I change to year view programmatically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, material-design, material-ui

I've a DatePicker

```
<DatePicker/>
```

in my component and it is rendered correctly, everything works properly but I need in my special use case only year view.

There is a function in a child component of DatePicker (Calendar):

```
yearSelector()
```

and it will called if I click on the year:

[image]

**My question is:** How can I call it programmatically, as far as DatePicker rendered in my component, so that I see only the year view like below:

[image]

Comment: You want to start picking your date with the year selector ?

Comment: You can only disable year selection (by default). You can fork the library on github. Change the code. Remove material-ui from your project. Then run "npm i --save http://yourGithubRepoLink"

Comment: Or you can try to generate a click on "2017" just after the date picker is open.

Comment: @Kornflexx thank you! How can I generate a click in the react-component, is there a proven way to do that? How can I address the correct div? The problem is, they have no IDs and have inline-styles. To do that in the DOM-Level would not be an elegant solution, don't you think so?

Comment: @ErkanBuelbuel I thinks this way is the baddest way to do it. To achieve it you have to wrap your datepicker in a div with an Id. Then look in the code viewer of your web browser to find how to select the element wich you need to click on it. In your datepick you can add the property "onShow", assign it a callback. In the callback retrieve the html element wich you need to click on (use the id of the wrapper to retreive it). Finally click on it.

Comment: If I understand correctly, You only want to display year selection - Have you tried this in the datepicker. 
<DatePicker selected={this.state.startDate} onChange={this.handleChange}  showYearDropdown />   so this way it defaults to current year selection.

Comment: @KaushalPatel : where did you find `showYearDropdown` props ?

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand, you want to force your calendar to first ask the user to select a year?

You can try this :

openToYearSelection={true}

You can see this code on [datepicker documentation](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker) and the [pullrequests](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/pull/6420)